# CustomValidator - validating against selected index with asp.net ServerValidateEventArgs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, selectedindex

I have the following code which works fine if checking whether the selected value of a dropdownlist is greater than 0.

However, I need to check against the selected index of the dropdownlist rather than the value.

```
Sub selectValidation(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
   Try
       args.IsValid = args.Value > 0
   Catch ex As Exception
       args.IsValid = False
   End Try
End Sub
```

Changing .Value to .SelectedIndex creates the following error:

```
BC30456: 'SelectedIndex' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs'.
```

EDIT:
Here's the validator code...

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Adults" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:CustomValidator id="Req_Adults"
     ControlToValidate="Adults"
     ClientValidationFunction="selectValidation"
     OnServerValidate="selectValidation"
     runat="server"
     CssClass="errorAsterisk"
     Text="*" 
     ErrorMessage="Select number of adults" />

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Children" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:CustomValidator id="Req_Children"
     ControlToValidate="Children"
     ClientValidationFunction="selectValidation"
     OnServerValidate="selectValidation"
     runat="server"
     CssClass="errorAsterisk"
     Text="*" 
     ErrorMessage="Select number of children" />
```

Clientside validation (working fine):

```
function selectValidation(source, arguments)
   {
        var selectedValue = $(source).siblings("select").prop("selectedIndex");
        if (selectedValue > 0 ){
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `DropDownList` is directly accessible from the handler, this works:

```
Sub selectValidation(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
    args.IsValid = Me.DropDownList1.SelectedIndex <> -1
End Sub
```

Otherwise you have to show us where it is. You canot get the reference from `source` or `args`.

A `CustomValidator` is the only validator which does not need to have a `ControlToValidate`. It can validate multiple controls, hence it wouldn't make sense to pass a control.

**Update**

I don't like this approach. However, if you really want to use the same handler you can assign a `ValidationGroup` to all relevant `DropDownLists` and use a query like this to find them:

```
Dim ddlNumZero = From ddl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of DropDownList)()
           Where ddl.ValidationGroup = "NumberValidation" _
           AndAlso ddl.SelectedIndex <= 0
args.IsValid = Not ddlNumZero.Any()
```

Comment: @Tom: I don't see how this edit could help. You should show us the markup, where is the `DropDownList` you want to find? Instead you show us the `CustomValidator`. My answer is about `CustomValidators` only, so that is nothing new. Note that is doesn't matter if you have set `ControlToValidate` or not since it's just a `String`.

Comment: OK... I've edited again... please let me know if there's anything else you need to see...

Comment: @Tom: I don't understand, have you tried to use my code and replace `DropDownList1` with `Adults`?

Comment: Sorry... I'm not being all that clear which is my fault. I am trying to avoid duplicating similar code by creating a single sub to validate many dropdownlists. They must all have a selectedIndex greater than 0. See the latest edit to the code. - Your code worked fine if I was only validating the one element.

Comment: @Tom: i don't like this approach, btw, how have you implemented the `ClientValidationFunction` because it should have the similar issue? If you really want to use the same handler you can assign a `ValidationGroup` to the relevant `DropDownLists` and use Linq to find them. Edited my answer.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I've added the clientside validation FYI.